# dynamically invoking a module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module in my lib dir with bunch of methods.

```
ModuleA extends self
  def testA
  end

  def testB
  end
end
```

I have a Controller where I wanted to call methods of ModuleA dynamically, say for example the method names is passed as params.

```
modul_method_from_params = "testA"
ModuleA::"#{modul_method_from_params}" #This gives me syntax error.
```

Any ideas on how I can access the methods elegantly?

Comment: duh!!! I was able to do ModuleA.send(modul_method_from_params)

Answer (score 1):

duh!!! I was able to do ModuleA.send(modul_method_from_params)